# Converting RSS Feed XML to JSON using Java is Displaying Special Characters

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, rss

Created a Spring MVC based Restful Controller which takes a hardcoded RSS HTTP URL and converts it from XML to JSON:

RssFeedController:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class RssFeedController {

    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    public RssFeedController() {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2/convertToJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String getRssFeedAsJson() throws IOException {
        InputStream xml = getInputStreamForURLData("http://www.samplefeed.com/feed");
        String xmlString = IOUtils.toString(xml);
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object json = objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Object.class);
        String response = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json);
        return response;
    }

    public static InputStream getInputStreamForURLData(String targetUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        InputStream content = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(targetUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
            content = (InputStream) httpConnection.getInputStream();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, the original RSS Feed has the following content:

```
<item>
    <title>October Fest Weekend</title>
    <link>http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend</link>
    <comments>http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend/#comments</comments>
    <pubDate>Wed, 04 Oct 2017 17:08:48 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[John Doe]]></dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[Uncategorized]]></category>

    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/?p=9227</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>
</p>
<p>Doors Open:6:30pm<br />
Show Begins:  7:30pm<br />
Show Ends (Estimated time): 11:00pm<br />
Location: Staples Center</p>
<p>Directions</p>
<p>Map of ...</p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend/">OctoberFest Weekend</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.samplefeed.com">SampleFeed</a>.</p>
]]></description>
```

This renders into JSON like this:

```
{
    "guid": {
        "content": "http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/?p=9227",
        "isPermaLink": false
    },
    "pubDate": "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 17:08:48 +0000",
    "category": "Uncategorized",
    "title": "October Fest Weekend",
    "description": "<p>\n??</p>\n<p>Doors Open:6:30pm<br />\nShow Begins:?? 7:30pm<br />\nShow Ends (Estimated time):??11:00pm<br />\nLocation: Staples Center</p>\n<p>Directions</p>\n<p>Map of ...</p>\n<p>The post <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend/\">OctoberFest Weekend</a> appeared first on <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.samplefeed.com\">Sample Feed</a>.</p>\n",
    "dc:creator": "John Doe",
    "link": "http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend",
    "comments": "http://www.samplefeed.com/feed/OctoberFestWeekend/#comments"
}
```

Please notice in the rendered JSON that there are two question marks ("??") right after inside the value for the "description" key like this:

```
"description": "<p>\n??</p>\n
```

Also, there are two more question marks right here after the Show Begins:

```
<br />\nShow Begins:??
```

And also before 11:00 p.m.

```
Show Ends (Estimated time):??11:00pm<br />
```

This isn't the only pattern that is displaying special characters, there also places where there are three ??? marks generated and also some places like ?????

e.g.

```
<title>Today’s 20th Annual Karaoke</title>
```

renders like this in JSON:

```
"title": "Today???s 20th Annual Karaoke"
```

And

```
<content-encoded>: <![CDATA[(Monte Vista High School, NY.).  </span></p>]]></content:encoded>
```

Renders like this in JSON:

```
"content:encoded":  "(Monte Vista High School, NY.).????</span></p>
```

There's places where the XML has a like a dash ("-"):

```
<strong>Welcome</strong> – Welcome to the Party!
```

Which gets rendered in JSON:

```
<strong>Welcome</strong>????? Welcome to the Party!
```

Does anyone know how to set the proper encoding in my code so I can avoid these bad / special characters rendering issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the unknown characters (???) like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/convertToJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public String getRssFeedAsJson() throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
    String xmlString = readUrlToString("http://www.sample.com/feed");
    JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
    byte[] ptext = xmlJSONObj.toString().getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
    String jsonResponse = new String(ptext, UTF_8); 
    return jsonResponse;
}

public static String readUrlToString(String url) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = null;
    String retValue = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setReadTimeout(2 * 1000);
        conn.connect();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        result = builder.toString();
        retValue = result.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ignoreOnClose) {
            }
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Disheartening that no one other than SamDev tried to help...

Answer (score 0):

> Converting RSS Feed XML to JSON using Java is Displaying Special
>   Characters

After review your code line by line I got the solution , I'm updating my answer for your
issues for special characters responce as **?**

If you update this line of your code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/convertToJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/convertToJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

You need to specify **UTF-8** charset encoding in produces param value with json. I'm sorry for my previous misunderstanding answer, However I update It Now.

Comment: I am confused... I am not using emojis - How would I use one of these libraries in my code? Can you provide me an example? What other encoding or charset would prevent this? Thanks for responding...

Comment: Unicode are not only for emojis, this cause when system is unable to render a stream it can be anything, so it display **?**. If you want to check what inside **?** use one of this java library and parse It, During run-time

Comment: Can you please show me some code using one of these?

Comment: When I used vdurmont emoji - it turned ? into Â

Comment: Yes, this the reason **Â** special characters not understand by JVM system, So It's print **?**

Comment: That really was an empty space... Am really confused on how to use your suggestions. Can you please provide some sample code using one of the libraries you mentioned? I really would appreciate and thank you again.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover I'm sorry for my previous misunderstanding answer, However I update It Now. Hope It'll help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156330/discussion-between-pacificnw-lover-and-samdev).

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover I would like to discussion on chat, But really It's not really a good time, Amworking in private organization.

Comment: Then can you just update your post to an example using one of the libs that you suggested?

Comment: Is this issue resolve after I update my answer **produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"**

Comment: No, putting produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"  replaces the ? with Â.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover As you seen the result for  **?** encoding turns into **Â** in both case (using 3rd party library **vdurmont emoji** and **produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"**) But How you sure about **That really was an empty space... Am really confused** , May you unable to recognized which **? .. ?? ..** for what.